# How can I use a Google Spreadsheet query to sum rows in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that spans 3 (work)Sheets.
On the first page I have a set of rows with customer data.

That looks like

```
C      D    E
Joe    -    100
Bob    -    200
Joe    -    300
Jane   -    50
```

And on sheet 2 I have a column with a formula that attempts to query those values and sum the purchase values for each customer (col E).

The formula I tried to use which fails is:

```
"=(QUERY('data'!B40:E60, "Select C, Sum(E) where C contains """&A18&""" Pivot C"))
```

In all seriousness though I really don't care about selecting C this is just the 20th variation I tried. What I am trying to do is sum E for all rows where C matches the cell A18 which is the customer name on sheet 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
=QUERY('data'!B40:E60, "Select C, Sum(E) where C = '"&A18&"' group by C")
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: Ok that actually works but wont display in a single cell. How can I shrink it down to just be the value of the sums and get rid of the rest?

Comment: =QUERY(data!B40:E60, "Select sum(E) where C = '"&$A$18&"' label sum(E)'' ") After label sum(E) two single quotes..

Answer (score 0):

Column A: Name
,
Column B: Amount

=QUERY(A1:B,"select A,sum(B) group by (A)")